# How to declare a "transposed" version of a type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I would like to define a TS function to transpose an object to array for instance:

```ts
const original  = { 
    value: [1, 2, 3], 
    label: ["one", "two", "three"] 
}

const transposed = [ 
    {value: 1, label: "one"}, 
    {value: 2, label: "two"},
    {value: 3, label: "three"}
]
```

Then I would like to declare a function that receives the `original` and outputs `transposed` and vice versa, like:

```ts
function tranpose(original: T): Array<T> // Incorrect, the output should be a transposed version of the object.
```

How can a define the transposed version of the object and correctly declare the function?

--

PS I'm not asking about implementations, just about the typing and declaration.

Comment: Are you asking about types or actual implementation? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYIHYEMA2UC8UDeUAblgK4QBcUqpAtgEYRwDaAugDRSbqOZUDOwRKiRsoAXwBQoSFAAqcdKn5gA9vwgATADxyAfLgJRmABShooAawghVAM3msqc06ygQAHsAipN-KACCcIog2mh2TFAAkgYA-NFQVKgQRJHiANySkpoQAMbccNB2pKi5wAiqqFBCSmoaunoAFKqIKBh88gCUVEEhuorKdVoNepmSuZWCUC3IaFhQhoSSCwskmORUzACMnABMnADMHFDLK9y8mwBElRCXnJfAAO6qd1APABaFt26SUuOTwGqAxU6i0hhqqCGzVac0wnUyEJBGk0zAADKwAHRrcgI4FDFHojHnCCYMaI-FozF2VSqKAAejpUBMcFUkDgoCgAHJqapOVBNKoIP5UKpAZ4EFNKtVwNAMXKgA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heh, you want `Transpose<Transpose<T>>` to yield something like `T`, right?  And I'm assuming, although it's not explicit in the question, that you want this to work for *arbitrary* objects-or-arrays which contain objects-or-arrays, not specifically "things with `value` and `label` properties that contain arrays".

That is conceptually easy, but things get hairy when dealing with objects-vs-arrays.  Even though [mapped types should produce array/tuples from array/tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), there are pitfalls where the compiler doesn't realize it's mapping an array/tuple until it's too late and your mapped type is full of awful array methods like `"length" | "push" | "pop" |...`.  I assume your implementation will also have some hairiness with this, but I'm worried about types here, not the implementation.

Here's my version, which works except for bit of weirdness with IntelliSense showing a union of identical types (like `type Foo = "a" | "a" | "a"` where you'd expect to see `type Foo = "a"`), which luckily doesn't affect how the types behave:

```
type Transpose<T> =
    T[Extract<keyof T, T extends readonly any[] ? number : unknown>] extends
    infer V ? { [K in keyof V]: { [L in keyof T]:
        K extends keyof T[L] ? T[L][K] : undefined } } : never;

declare function transpose<T>(t: T): Transpose<T>;
```

The explanation is that we are walking though the *value*/*element* types of `T` to figure out what the keys of the output type should be.  That should be `T[keyof T]` but we need to do `T[Extract<keyof T, ...]` to make sure that arrays don't mess things up.  Then we mostly just turn `T[K][L]` into `T[L][K]` with some type checks along the way.

---

Let's test it.  We need a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) or something like it if you want the compiler to keep track of which values are at which keys:

```
const original = {
    value: [1, 2, 3],
    label: ["one", "two", "three"]
} as const
/* const original: {
    readonly value: readonly [1, 2, 3];
    readonly label: readonly ["one", "two", "three"];
} */
```

Now we'll transpose it:

```
const transposed = transpose(original);
/* readonly [{
    readonly value: 1;
    readonly label: "one";
}, {
    readonly value: 2;
    readonly label: "two";
}, {
    readonly value: 3;
    readonly label: "three";
}]
*/


transposed.forEach(v => v.label) // transposed is seen as an array
transposed[1].label // known to be "two"
```

Looks good.  If you use IntelliSense on `transposed` you will see it as a union  of three identical types, but ‍♂️.  (This is a known design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#16582](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16582).  It's possible to force the compiler to aggressively reduce unions, as shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-c2+bg40Wlko90Z3OmfLngAdCiEGCYeoE2RcO8yLeFqmYBYLDAy2LWVjDaXFDGMRpDHgBpfEIQC2k8ZgeC-JdsD-eV2U5ACQBgUQV2WKp8wSAB5Rwa2wUtr0eJMqIQutqlsMwSLI5xVXiBcZiCDjmDYTgYF4fdG37Rc0nobjRlUJYChXQ4SlHcpKkILRSOrZwULSW9aXQJoEwhd8YD0gBqNQAEJJDrX9-2UlisHUsRgJgUDtSMQxnOg9BYKqKp0P+KBKHgaN1GuSQhGgFYxGoWlcVgPV0BgFkozgy5rnVIwoGIlF406BMcsxE08QgsB-CpXT6ATH8cHeNN9LIEBEA6T1qG9eAf3y-EtWFRkPkpeJusa5rWpxAqYByiF6CFEUYAASQqj86s8H8qSmplqSakVBr5Ybyv0hMJsZX5FviX4Vq9EV-QuK4YC+KN-k8QFnjeTpUugDKsra4w9pgTUqUhYNKEDF42HVd53o6yaAA0eqmBhwZ5Ib2o1a0vpW36+gB9U2HB94AB8ru+P4ASBJ4sZOtbGX6n0gA), but that isn't really the point of this question, so I digress.)  The output type is seen as a tuple, so it has all the array methods, which I assume you want.

Then we're supposed to be able to obtain the original again by transposing the transposed thing:

```
const reOriginal = transpose(transposed);
/* const reOriginal: {
    readonly value: readonly [1, 2, 3];
    readonly label: readonly ["one", "two", "three"];
} */

reOriginal.label.map(x => x + "!"); // reOriginal.label is seen as an array
```

Again, looks good.  The type of `reOriginal` is (modulo IntelliSense) the same as the type of `original`.  Hooray!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANjAvDA3gFAwkwBuWArgKYBcMA2gIwA0MATGwMwC6LxpTOgBG1TPQYAicNUltJUAO4g5MBQAt41WT0IBfGOggxQkKIQD0AKhPhocJKgziCAklvQATcJgCe5KjoYD28wP0ZWDm4eAG43YOovH38hURcQ5MZpMFl5JRU8zW1JWP0YKwtCSytTeyh4dEgABxAIak9cRnj8AMwaekjUsXps2Rg9flICXv6omCGXBWVJccnSHoo+oK42BZGoIrG9Qh4KqqhfJuoYABUG5tbqAB4bgD5ceJuGAFEAD3r0MAoE8ANbUXwgABmtzYNxg1H+1DAnmMGTC-kavgYPBgAH4YGBKABbUTwGD0ShgEFgECKMCvHEIqBIlHxNCQ6hkgBqeOmDAA0jA0DAwRDoVyePQegwADJCsAi8FQ26S+JTQVMlnGUXKr4ynH4vU8AU4inI6iQtDtcY2+g5MicuJVTzUYBCLQwSGUoGIcAwAEPNovV4ACig9BuAEoI-cIC0g28nbVYAG448OnhU-HqCGECg0FhI3FrAkkujGEQpmjwptZkw4lXEqFwns1DJJHEJq5G2Wa4F6OwG6RqykRMM1PkO-o2JXh03MrXtkP3PPy62NFpZJ3dGdzrHs54AHSQhDfQHqENkXDvMiHhaRmAWCz+-fpoXGNpIwzGRqGeANXxCCzdNmB4O8x2wJ8RRpOl-RAGBRAnZYqmTBIAHlHALbBM1fNow1w9oi2qWwzHQzDnCleIRxmIJqOYNhOBgXhl1LZtRzSeg6NGVQlgKCdDhKTtykqQgtAw-NnHAtJDyJdAmhDX5rxgRSAGo1AAQkkItH2fMTyKwKSxHfGBPwVIxDDM-90EAoA)

[Playground link to code with IntelliSense fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-c2+bg40Wlko90Z3OmfLngAdCiEGCYeoE2RcO8yLeFqmYBYLDAy2LWVjDaXFDGMRpDHgBpfEIQC2k8ZgeC-JdsD-eV2U5ACQBgUQV2WKp8wSAB5Rwa2wUtr0eJMqIQutqlsMwSLI5xVXiBcZiCDjmDYTgYF4fdG37Rc0nobjRlUJYChXQ4SlHcpKkILRSOrZwULSW9aXQJoEwhd8YD0gBqNQAEJJDrX9-2UlisHUsRgJgUDtSMQxnOg9BYKqKp0P+KBKHgaN1GuSQhGgFYxGoWlcVgPV0BgFkozgy5rnVIwoGIlF406BMcsxE08QgsB-CpXT6ATH8cHeNN9LIEBEA6T1qG9eAf3y-EtWFRkPkpeJusa5rWpxAqYByiF6CFEUYAASQqj86s8H8qSmplqSakVBr5Ybyv0hMJsZX5FviX4Vq9EV-QuK4YC+KN-k8QFnjeTpUugDKsra4w9pgTUqUhYNKEDF42HVd53o6yaAA0eqmBhwZ5Ib2o1a0vpW36+gB9U2HB94AB8ru+P4ASBJ4sZOtbGX6n0gA)

Comment: FYI, I just had a need to do exactly this while working on the Reselect library. I googled `typescript transpose tuples`, this was the top hit, and this snippet worked exactly as I hoped it would. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 7):

If you need a type that checks if the original type is *exactly* transposed, you first need to use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) `as const` on the original (or types of elements of mutable arrays under `value` and `label` keys will be widened).

---

There is a way to type the transpose without resorting to generating indices which results in a more concise and robust type (the rest of the logic is the same as in the utility below):

```ts
const original = { 
    value: [1, 2, 3], 
    label: ["one", "two", "three"] 
} as const;

type T2<T extends { value: readonly number[], label: readonly string[] }> = {
    [ P in keyof Omit<T["value"], keyof readonly any[]> ] : { value: T["value"][P], label: P extends keyof T["label"] ? T["label"][P] : never }
}  & readonly any[];

type test = T2<typeof original>;

const transposed: test = [
    { value: 1, label: "one" },
    { value: 2, label: "two" },
    { value: 3, label: "three" }
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBOBLA5osBDANjAvDA3jAFAykwBuWArgKYBcMA2gIwA0MATOwMwC67JMpnQAjGpgaMAROBpT2UqAHcQ8mIoAW8GnN7EAvjHQQYoSFADcRIlACeABxowAKhwA8zmDQAeUGmAATE0JKTFoGbXQA8ExbGDAqAFsxeEZ%20GGExCRhI6LBYmGgkMGQ0mH0APlwCQVJGGAAFGDQYAGsaWxAAMxgAeUTEKA9pUNopdPbOntyYuPQwWzSqvQYQ6noXEfXxxgb0zPEGJp8-QJNJ7s2pA8xxmAB%20K5udvZgGMBpyGnhyokMYABkORoUVmRgWaSsNgcTj80GqrjcdkclwQKDQWAqULM8Kg8HmEHsIAgNACDDhsDwjFqBAo6wYbAyokO6lkUnKrBpazCGy4TKyDEUKnZ%20k5ZFpow23HYN0FUC0OhFRF4FiAA)

---

**Recursive version**

Next, you have to generate enough indices to ensure the elements in the resulting tuple are positioned correctly. This can be done with recursive conditional types, but beware of the recursion depth limits (~23 in this implementation):

```ts
type GenIndices<L extends number, A extends any[] = []> = Omit<A["length"] extends L ? A : GenIndices<L, [...A, A["length"]]>, keyof any[]>;

type test = GenIndices<3>; //{0: 0; 1: 1; 2: 2; }
```

Finally, you need to map the indices to the corresponding values in tuples under the keys of the original type (note that unless you guarantee that `P extends keyof T[<key here>]`, you will not be able to use indices to index the properties):

```ts
type Transpose<T extends { value: readonly number[], label: readonly string[] }> = {
    [ P in keyof GenIndices< T["value"]["length"] > ] : P extends keyof T["value"] ? 
    P extends keyof T["label"] ? 
    { value: T["value"][P], label: T["label"][P] } : 
    never : 
    never;
} & readonly any[];
```

That's it, let's test how the utility works:

```ts
const original = { 
    value: [1, 2, 3], 
    label: ["one", "two", "three"] 
} as const;

//Transpose implemenetation

type test = Transpose<typeof original>;

const ok: test = [ 
    {value: 1, label: "one"}, 
    {value: 2, label: "two"},
    {value: 3, label: "three"}
];

const err: test = [ 
    {value: 2, label: "one"}, //Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'
    {value: 2, label: "two"},
    { label: "three" } //Property 'value' is missing
];
```

And the `transpose` function could look like this:

```ts
declare function tranpose<T extends typeof original>(original: T): Transpose<T>;
const test2 = tranpose(original)[2]; //{ value: 3; label: "three"; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2BJeATAlgYwgZwDwBkoIAPYBFbKeAVwFsAjCAJwBooBBI08ygQ3hABtALpQAvFBEA+cVADytNMFztBAIgA2CAObAAFmtEkyqSoQD8HKAC5YCZOix58bQQDoP7Nqs079h4Sk2AGsIEAB7ADMofiFAgG4AWAAoFNBIKAAVJn5sMHDsCFxMrhMKKABvKAA3Xg1qCFsmCF4UcPgNECo6RiYRNg1eRg0mlraOruxgJjR4bREoAF8ZCQqUqA3JKAAFKFmoUIjouCRUTBxcLPVa+ohDdS05-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)

Comment: Nice solution, with the `GenIndices`, your playground link is missing a domain though.

Comment: @Oblosys - ouch, thanks! Seems like I somehow copied only the code part of the link

Answer (score 3):

I get, this question is about the typing, not the implementation of that function.

```
function tranpose<T extends Record<keyof any, readonly any[]>>(original: T): {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never
}[] {
    // implementation is up to you
    return [];
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-CMEiXM3UegwNgwYRiCTqWRSE0TshTg0zrjz0TiBhy1Qm4Gbi3cdgL-fqRXaOSwhmM5nQbjsr0+yKMekWIA)

or as a type

```
type Transpose<T extends Record<keyof any, readonly any[]>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : never
}[];
```

This doesn't care what or how many properties the input has, as long as they are some kind of array.

What it can't do is map the respective indices in these arrays or ensure that all arrays have the same length, that's something you have to deal with when implementing the function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is alternative veriosn:

```js
type Origin = Readonly<{
    value: ReadonlyArray<any>,
    label: ReadonlyArray<any>
}>
type Reduce<T extends Origin, Result extends ReadonlyArray<any> = []> =
    T extends { value: [], label: [] }
    ? Result
    : T extends { value: [infer V], label: [infer L] }
    ? [...Result, { value: V, label: L }]
    : T extends { value: [infer Val, ...infer Vals], label: [infer Label, ...infer Labels] }
    ? Reduce<{ value: Vals, label: Labels }, [...Result, { label: Label, value: Val }]>
    : Result


type Test = Reduce<{ label: [1, 2, 3], value: ['1','2', '3'] }>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHkBOBLA5sgdrAvLAStAIYAmA9hgDbgA8A3sLI7AG6EUCu0AXPkWZeACCiRIRqEM4AHwAaBkwqEARtAo8CJclWGjxkqcAC%20BiDF7F2AY2jUAKrGgAPUNAzEAzghToMM3u-YKUAdnVw9eTQEdMWoJaRxYAG0AXSkceUZ7Jxc3T1oWNk4eFL9FFTUk5NhDDNgAfn9A0FqeLNDc2HzWDm4kzAAzaERYADVk0uVVYoGh2AAZKpqmeqSAOnWCAKC-LsLekYnynjnq5JbYNpzw3Z7pjEHhkbY-ddWZx7Z3cdgyqb772ZzSYUF7rd7zYFfaq1BoECzWOgFW6jT6HP5A8qeQx%20RKvTZNHY-YHHYF%20bpFFEUU4GZbqaBbZogUxwWz04K4OFWGz5X4VRIARj8ACY-ABmb7k3qJADk-OlMmlQvlsGlouliwMwCAA)

Answer (score 2):

You could use generics in the types of the object fields

```
function transpose<A,B>(original:{value:A[], label:B[]}): { value:A, label:B }[] {
    const objs:  {value:A, label:B}[] = [];
    original.value.forEach( (value, i) => {
        const label = original.label[i];
        objs.push({label, value}); 
    });
    return objs;
}

const obj = {
    value: [ 1,2,3 ],
    label: ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
};

console.log(transpose(obj));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZwA50wUwB4BBAGgCEA%20ACjhRgHMYw0AbALgG8A3NkfdsQDaAXVKJWaAEb4O5UQF8AlO0SdEvVv0HjJMuYgWi1AKETnEEBJiiI4UgFaZVazdrITps9uSMjEALyIogDcZhZ0jMxsAHRu%20DHAdACiaBAAFtSI1PHiMEqBlKYWJZbWtnqygXb0TCysMZWsQjAiYaURjpgx2CCYmZxN4vHKIYjh5qMTiCj4UCAoSPZOYQomJlZYtsvVnNPxqkKIAIykAEykAMyIYtNNhwDkAPJg%20A-iDwAqAO5w74hfdKzN4iEwKMIbaxwVgJVhwBjUVAYHB4fC0RxKJQhIA)